# Custom Authentication and Autherization in Silverlight 5 Prism 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, ado.net, devart

How I can custom Implement Authorization and Authentication in Prism 4.1 Silverlight 5 Application. I'm Trying to implement Authentication Domain Service but IUser Interface & pre Shipped User : UserBase is giving issue.

I want to know what schema I require? what configuration I require. 
I also have confusion about the way Authentication Domain Service works.

Comment: Please edit your question: only show the relevant parts of your code, avoid horizontal scrolling and ask a clear question. For instance: it is not clear where the exceptions are thrown, nor is it clear what you're trying to achieve. **OR** (even better) reproduce the issue in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, this made it far worse. Far too broad.